# Remove trailing and leading spaces and extra internal whitespace with one gsub call

Tags: regex, r

I know you can remove trailing and leading spaces with

```
gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
```

And you can remove internal spaces with

```
gsub("\\s+"," ",x)
```

I can combine these into one function, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with just one use of the `gsub` function

```
trim <- function (x) {
  x <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$|", "", x)
  gsub("\\s+", " ", x)
}

testString<- "  This is a      test. "

trim(testString)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
gsub("^ +| +$|( ) +", "\\1", testString)  # with Frank's input, and Agstudy's style
```

We use a capturing group to make sure that multiple internal spaces are replaced by a single space.  Change " " to `\\s` if you expect non-space whitespace you want to remove.

Answer (score 8):

Using a positive lookbehind :

```
gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$",'',testString,perl=TRUE)
# "This is a test."
```

Explanation :

```
## "^ *"     matches any leading space 
## "(?<= ) "    The general form is (?<=a)b : 
             ## matches a "b"( a space here)
             ## that is preceded by "a" (another space here)
## " *$"     matches trailing spaces
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just add `\\s+(?=\\s)` to your original regex:

```
gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$|\\s+(?=\\s)", "", x, perl=T)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/35)

Answer (score 4):

You've asked for a `gsub` option and gotten good options. There's also `rm_white_multiple` from "qdapRegex":

```
> testString<- "  This is a      test. "
> library(qdapRegex)
> rm_white_multiple(testString)
[1] "This is a test."
```

Answer (score 1):

If an answer not using `gsub` is acceptable then the following does it. It does not use any regular expressions:

```
paste(scan(textConnection(testString), what = "", quiet = TRUE), collapse = " ")
```

giving:

```
[1] "This is a test."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use nested `gsub`. Less elegant than the previous answers tho

```
> gsub("\\s+"," ",gsub("^\\s+|\\s$","",testString))
[1] "This is a test."
```

Comment: Isn't this similar to the OP's function

Comment: It is, but in one line :)